# Will Service Worker Query Cache Algorithm Allow Expression Matching URL paths?

Tags: service-worker, fetch-api

I discovered a use case for matching Request urls using an expression that ignores part of a url path (*path* not *ignoreSearch*).

The use case is for an image processing service used in a responsive design where the dimensions of the image are encoded in the url path. This is sort of common among these kinds of services (Cloudinary, Firesize, even Lorempixel).

I noticed every once in a while, one of the dimension components will request will be off by one pixel. The required dimensions are calculated from the client - source of the error is rounding [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight) - But the service worker cache could be an elegant solution for this variation.
However, this rounding problem results in a cache miss because I can't specify that part of the url path can be ignored.

**Will url expression matching ever become part of the spec?
In general, is it ok that the 'fetch with url A, cache put/match with url B' pattern grow?**

I get that the work around for this is the same as the current work around for ignoreSearch (until its implementation), wherein you fetch with one url but cache with another. I'm just wondering if url path expression matching will ever become part of the spec, or if an url expression matching use case has been considered. I don't see any evidence of this in the authoritative spec.

Thanks in advance for any words of insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be considered at some point in the future if it becomes a dominant pattern in many applications. Usually if something is fairly common it'll eventually be included in the standard so it can be made faster and more reliable. I wouldn't count on it happening anytime soon though and without many libraries having support for it.